# list view in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

How to implement the list view like android in blackberry and its change listener?

---

|        | Text1
| Image  | Text2
|***_*_**|

Comment: Edit:Make your own CustomeListCallBack by extending the ListCallback.

then override the drawListRow() method to draw your custom row.

Draw the bitmap in the method.

 

then add that callback into your listField. something like:
CustomeListCallBack callback = new CustomeListCallBack();
ListField field = new ListField();
for(int i = 0; i<data.lenght; i++)
{
    callback.insert(data, image etc);
    field.insert(i); //insert new row in list.
}
list.setCallback(callBack);
callback.insert(); will be a method in your Callback Class handling your insertion through vector or array.